# OpenConnect GUI на Linux. Как сбросить пароль пользователя, который сохранили по умолчанию

Tags: linux, vpn, cisco

Имеем: Linux Mint
OpenConnect GUI

При создании настроек соединения для cisco поставил галку "сохранить пароль". Пользователь подключался к VPN без ввода пароля (пароль вводился по умолчанию). Сейчас возникла необходимость использования этого соединения другим пользователем на этой машине. Пользователь должен заходить под другим паролем.
Как вариант - удалить все настройки текущего соединения и создать по новому. Но может есть команда для сброса пароля по умолчанию?

Comment: а новый пользователь будет использовать тот же логин для входа в систему (в линукс, не впн)? Может ему завести новый и тогда проблема решится сама (как и ряд других). Но если нет, тогда просто возьмите и выберите в меню "редактировать подключение" и там просто удалите пароль